# show checkbox value checked/unchecked from mongo data in meteor

Tags: meteor

i have created collection named as "tbl_dynamic" in that a field named "dynamicField" created in that i'm storing data like this

```
"_id":"LoBTiSo3oqr54Ac5R",
"text":"test",
"dynamicField" : {
        "text1" : {
            "checkedValue" : false
        },
        "text2" : {
            "checkedValue : true
        }
    }
```

and in meteor side i have a template like this

```
<template name="tmpChecked">
<input id="newField" name="field" type="text" placeholder="Field" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" value={{key}}>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input id="chkChecked" type="checkbox" name="chk_checked" checked={{checkedValue}}>
                </label>
            </div>
</template>
```

and my helper contains following code to fetch data from collection

```
//helper to view fields
Template.tmpChecked.helpers({
    values: function() {
        return tbl_dynamic.find({},{dynamicField:1,text:1});
    }
});
```

now the problem is when i tried to display checkbox value it doesn't show me the checkedValue.

any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to show list of checkboxes and each checkbox followed by input box.

For this, You need to do following 2 things -

1. Change the data model little bit. Make the `dynamicField` properties  as the  array. Each array element containing information about field name and checked property

> ```
> {
>  "_id":"LoBTiSo3oqr54Ac5R", 
>  "text":"test", 
>  "dynamicField" : [
>         {   
>             "name": "text1",
>             "checkedValue" : false
>          },
>          {    
>             "name": "text2",
>             "checkedValue : true
>          }
>     ]
> }
> ```

2.In template code, iterate over objects `dynamicFields` array and display them

```
<template name="tmpChecked">
 {{#with values}}
   {{ #each dynamicField}}
       <input id="newField" name="field" type="text" placeholder="Field" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" value={{name}}>
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input id="chkChecked" type="checkbox" name="chk_checked" checked={{checkedValue}}>
                </label>
            </div>
 {{/each}}
{{/with}}

</template>
```

You can keep helper function as it is. No need to change.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for new suggestion, but i don't want to change my data model. it nice if you have any alternate without changing data model.